# Can you add anchors in redactor?

Tags: redactor

I know if I turn off Purify HTML I might be able to get anchors working in Redactor rich text fields, but I want the ole client to be able to insert anchor links.

Does a plugin for this exist, or is it possible to make an 'insert anchor' button on my own easily?

Answer (score 2):

I ended up getting this great plugin called Redactor Extras
https://github.com/elliotlewis/Redactor-Extras

Installed easily, and it has a properties option that it adds to rich text fields that lets you add a class or id to a piece of text. I just add id=something and then link to #something. Works like a charm for adding anchors!